# How to move image around square

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have a square image (like a board) with 10 fields each side. I am trying to move around this board, stepping into fields(like token/pawn in board game, one step is one filed). After 10 steps I have to change direction (up, left, right, down). I am trying to do any animations, change image position in every iterate in loop but it is working only once.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < range; ++i) {
            asX = token.getX();
            asY = token.getY();
            moveLength = 2.5f;
            if (1 case) {
                token.animate().x(asX - (2.5f * token.getWidth())).y(asY);
            } else if (2 case) {
                token.animate().x(asX - (2.5f * token.getWidth())).y(asY);
            } else if (3 case) {
                token.animate().x(asX - (2.5f * token.getWidth())).y(asY);
            } else if (4 case) {
              token.animate().x(asX - (2.5f * token.getWidth())).y(asY);
            }
            position++;
            token.invalidate();
        }
```

```
range is a number of moves,
1 case - move left,
2 case - move up,
3 case - move rigth,
4 case - move down
```

so for example when range=6 and pos=0(token at the starting field), token should move by 6 fields to the left(cause pos < 10 and range also < 10), next when range=8 and pos=6, token should move by 4 fields to the left and then 4 fileds up etc.
It move only by one filed, not range.
Any idea?

Comment: Hmmmm... will Need more of your code to make a precise Judgement.. Probably the fault is at `posX` & `posY` variables...

Comment: i have just edited

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectAnimator class has new constructors that enable you to animate coordinates

for more please read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view#java)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  Path path = new Path();
  path.arcTo(0f, 0f, 1000f, 1000f, 270f, -180f, true);
  ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, View.Y, path);
  animator.setDuration(2000);
  animator.start();
} else {
  // Create animator without using curved path
}
```

Comment: yeah, buts my animation/path depends on the range and current position of tokens that is why i have tried with loop